# ViewPager setOnPageChangeListener not working

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

Someone have idea where is problem? I can not get on page change listener to work. I need get actual position when page is changed but not working. I find a lot but problem is still here. Thx for time.

**public class SuperFragmentHome extends Fragment**

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    PagerCustomHorizontalScrollView tabs = (PagerCustomHorizontalScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.pagerTabs);
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    //pager.setCurrentItem(1);
    //pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
    //pager.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new HomeFragment());
    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

        }
    });

    tabs.setViewPager(pager);
}
```

And I have also adapter class in class SuperFragmentHome

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    DayCalculator dayCalc = new DayCalculator();
    String s1 = dayCalc.getNameOfDayOfWeek(-1) + " " + dayCalc.getDateOfDayOfWeek(-1);
    String s2 = dayCalc.getNameOfDayOfWeek(0) + " " + dayCalc.getDateOfDayOfWeek(0);
    String s3 = dayCalc.getNameOfDayOfWeek(1) + " " + dayCalc.getDateOfDayOfWeek(1);
    String s4 = dayCalc.getNameOfDayOfWeek(2) + " " + dayCalc.getDateOfDayOfWeek(2);
    String s5 = dayCalc.getNameOfDayOfWeek(3) + " " + dayCalc.getDateOfDayOfWeek(3);
    String s6 = dayCalc.getNameOfDayOfWeek(4) + " " + dayCalc.getDateOfDayOfWeek(4);

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    private final String[] TITLES = {s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6};

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return TITLES[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return TITLES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return HomeFragment.newInstance(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: onPageSelected() gives you the actual position.

Comment: Does the page changing work?

Comment: no page selected is not called, listener not working, yes page changing work great

Comment: I can get position from  HomeFragment newInstance(int position) but  position is not changing for first and last tab in pager .(